# How do l-value functions work in c++?

Tags: c++, function, lvalue

How do reference-type functions work when they are used as l-values? I mean, what is the order in which things get done in such a function so that the return variable gets a new value and how is it different from what happens in a normal r-value function?

For example in the following piece of code,

```
double& matrix::operator()(int i, int j) const //parenthesis operator
{
  if (!validdex(*this,i,j)) throw(-23); //index out of bounds
  return mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)]; //A(i,j)=mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)]
}
```

which is used to overload parentheses for instances of a class named matrix (validdex chacks if k is a valid index for the matrix), I need to know how the way in which the function (the paranthesis operator in this case) is processed differs when it is used as an r-value (to get `mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)]`) from when it is used as an l-value (to set the value of `mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)]`).

Sorry if the question is vague or if it sounds too basic. I tried to find the answer on the web but I didn't find anything besides some very basic tutorials on l-value functions with only a return line and nothing else.

Comment: Can you give code examples on what exactly you're stuck on? What is an l-value function to you?

Comment: @GManNickG I have difficulty understanding the way in which reference-type functions work. By l-value function, I mean reference-type functions used as l-values.

Comment: @MohammadSanei Please give a minimal code to show it. Do you mean functions that return a reference?

Comment: @Etherealone Yes I mean functions that return a reference, when used as an l-value.

Comment: You're using the terms lvalue and rvalue in a strange way. Back up and try to explain what you're confused about without these terms, if you can.

Comment: There's nothing strange or confusing about the question or its use of terms (other than hyphenating them). Anyone who knows that a function that returns a reference can be used as an lvalue should have no trouble understanding the question. "Do you mean functions that return a reference?" -- that's obvious from the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function returns a reference you can think of it as though the function were returning a pointer. Functions that return references do not interact in any special way with the calling code. Such special interaction is not necessary to use a function call expression as an lvalue: The function returns its pointer and then it's done; The calling code just uses the pointer value.